# Prevent multi table from producing empty lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to prevent `Table` from producing `{}` in multi tables?

For simple table we can prevent this by `Nothing`:

```
Table[If[i == 5, i, Nothing], {i, 10}]
Do[If[i == 5, Print[i]], {i, 10}]

(* {5} *)
(* 5 *)
```

But for multi tables it does not work:

```
Table[If[i == 5 && j == 5, {i, j}, Nothing], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
Do[If[i == 5 && j == 5, Print[{i, j}]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]

(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {{5, 5}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
(* {5,5} *)
```

If we had instead of `10` iterations, say `10^6`, iterations it would be a problem because of lots of unnecessary `{}`.

For comparison you can also see the same code with `Do` but I would like to avoid it.

Of course we can remove `{}` afterwards, but this is not the question.

Comment: `Sequence @@@ 
 Table[If[i == 5 && j == 5, Sequence @@ {i, j}, Nothing], {i, 10}, {j,
    10}]` ?

Comment: Nothing deletes a single element, not a whole row.  You may replace empty rows by ... /. {}->Nothing

Comment: Of course we can remove `{}` afterwards but empty lists are produced anyway, which slows down code and increases used memory for large value of iterations.

Comment: Can you show us something closer to your actual code? This example is just too unrealistic to help us understand the problem.

Comment: If you're worried about minimizing memory and avoiding unnecessary calculations, then I think `Table` is just a bad choice, and I'm not sure `Do` is much better. But again, without a realistic example, it's difficult to offer suggestions. And for performance improvements it's impossible to give help without knowing the actual scope and complexity of the real problem.

Comment: The difficulty is that the multitable  wraps each element by `List`, and `Nothing` appears inside them. Try this: `Flatten[Table[
  If[i == 5 && j == 5, {i, j}, Nothing], {i, 10}, {j, 10}], 2]`

Comment: maybe `Array[If[# == 5 && #2 == 5, {##}, {}] &, {10, 10}, 1, Join]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[If[i == 5, Table[If[j == 5, {i, j}, Nothing], {j, 10}], 
  Nothing], {i, 10}]
```

> {{{5, 5}}}

### Updated:

```
If[#[[1]] == 5 && #[[2]] == 5, #, Nothing] & /@ Tuples[Range[10], 2]
```

> {{5, 5}}

```
If[#[[1]] + #[[2]] == 5, #, Nothing] & /@ Tuples[Range[10], 2]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}}

However, I prefer @kglr's solution from the comments:

```
Array[If[# == 5 && #2 == 5, {##}, {}] &, {10, 10}, 1, Join]
```

> {5, 5}

Comment: Yes this work in this specific case, but in general if the condition cannot be separated like  for `If[i+j==5,...]` it will not work. But anyway +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps avoiding `Do` is not so important here:

```
Catenate@
 Last@
  Reap@
   Do[If[i == 5 && j == 5, Sow[{i, j}]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```